# Can't compare and print SQL result in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I need help with this simple yet important for me task. I have the following code, where I am trying to extract id from a table, then compare it to a number, then simply print it.

```
track_id=cur.execute("SELECT id FROM files WHERE track_title='re.mp3';")

self.assertEqual(track_id, "2")

print track_id
```

I get an error because track_id returns 'none'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM files WHERE track_title='re.mp3';")
track_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: thank you for the help, could you please tell me what does cur.fetchone()[0] do? I understand fetchone gets one result, but what does the [0] do?

Comment: It gets the value of the first column.  If your query was "SELECT id, track_title FROM files ...", cur.fetchone()[1] would get the value of the second column, track_title.